# What makes nsjail's disable_no_new_privs dangerous?

Tags: jail, namespaces

The documentation of [nsjail](https://github.com/google/nsjail) states that `disable_no_new_privs` is dangerous:

> ```
> --disable_no_new_privs   
> Don't set the prctl(NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1) (DANGEROUS)
> ```

The [kernel docs](https://docs.kernel.org/userspace-api/no_new_privs.html) point out that

> For example, the setuid and setgid bits will no longer change the uid or gid;

So now I am wondering: In cases where I need to have setuid binaries, what am I risking by setting `disable_no_new_privs: true`?

The kernel docs say

> no_new_privs + chroot is considerable less dangerous than chroot by itself.

but does this mean there is danger of an nsjail escape? Or what does dangerous mean here?

Answer (score 1):

Double negatives are confusing. When that option is true, [nsjail does not set the flag](https://github.com/google/nsjail/blob/3.4/contain.cc#L80):

```c
if (!nsjconf->disable_no_new_privs) {
        if (prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1UL, 0UL, 0UL, 0UL) == -1) {
```

Its not that there are necessarily known vulnerabilities or escapes. In general, its much more difficult to secure a process that is authorized to do anything, and thus find a way out of its box.

What you gain by not having setuid or fcap programs is if those are compromised doing things at a higher privilege. With it on (jail option of disabled not set), the kernel is making a guarantee that even if a setuid program were compromised and did a malicious execve(), that wouldn't do anything privileged. For example, say someone slipped in a bad update to sudo. No setuid makes sudo rather useless though, you would want some other means of changing effective user.

Compare to the ping program on Linux. [Fedora let everyone send ICMP echo](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/EnableSysctlPingGroupRange), allowing people to do network diagnostics without needing cap_net_admin or cap_net_raw. There might exist ways to do whatever your application needs without extra privileges.

Comment: Thanks, and good point about alternative ways! What is confusing me is this: If we assume the worst and I actually have a setuid binary that allows arbitrary command execution as root inside the jail, then it is still just *inside* the jail, right? So is it just dangerous within the nsjail?

Comment: A sandbox or jail is only useful for security if it correctly filters system calls and other OS interactions. While there are mature implementations out there, taking defense in depth seriously means questioning why programs in the sandbox need to be privileged. Assume someone put the wrong nsjail config into place, and in the sandbox someone expoits a setuid binary to run a privileged program.  Maybe they can make a device of the root file system and escape.  Unlikely, but strong limits on getting new privileges makes it far more difficult.